# divide my site into blocks

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of building a site and I would like have my entire site on one page. I was looking at these sites for inspiration but I can't figure out how they divide the site into those different blocks. When I try to do that and style them all that happens is: for example

```
<p>
bla bla
</p>
```

when I style P obviously it only applies color for as far as the text reaches and leaves the rest of the page blank.

Here are some examples. (http://clovercaremassage.ca/) and (http://deacupunctuurpraktijk.nl/)

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example sites you've shown are of a [parallax style](https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2013/08/15/what-parallax-web-design-%E2%80%93-definitions-tips-considerations). Here's a very basic template to get you started. The keys in this example are the height of each 'block' being the height of the screen 100vh (100% of viewport height) and the background of the second block being fixed (doesn't scroll with page). This example doesn't use any animations or scroll speed offsets that help make some of the good designs so compelling. If you're not a coder you can find many [wordpress themes that utilize parallax](https://themeforest.net/search/parallax), all you have to do is install one and fill in the content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.section:nth-child(1) { background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 1); }
.section:nth-child(2) { background: url("https://i.imgur.com/hHBx4Ji.jpg") no-repeat fixed center; }
.section:nth-child(3) { background-color: hsla(50, 30%, 70%, 1); }
```

```html
<div class="section">block 1</div>
<div class="section">block 2</div>
<div class="section">block 3</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/hL7mu7mt/